# How to harmonize descending ^2 ^7 ^5 in the soprano in the same bar

Tags: voice-leading

If these melody notes appear in a harmony exercise where you are allowed to use only V V7 and I to harmonize a melody would the logic be too harmonize all 3 with V since you are going from the leading tone down to the 5th scale degree and in the soprano the leading tone would resolve to ^1 unless the V chord was being extended. Similarly, if you see ^4 going to ^5 then would the logic be to also use V7 for both since you wouldnt have a 7th not resolving down in the soprano unless the dominant harmony is being extended?

Comment: Might make more sense if the example was shown - note values and places in the bar can affect what harmonies work more effectively.

Comment: Even only using V and I there are tons of options. The 2nd scale degree can sound great as a ninth above the root of the I chord. Similarly with the 7th scale degree. And of course the fifth degree is a chord tone for both. It’s kinda like there’s no wrong answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can harmonize 2-7-5 with only V, you could also with V7, or you could e.g. use V for the first two notes and V7 for the last one to add movement and tension.

Using V7 for 4–5 makes sense if you're limited to I and V and V7, indeed otherwise non-resolving 7th would be an issue. Maybe an alternative could be to treat 4 as a passing note, then you could harmonize both notes with I?

Comment: Thanks. In this case each note in the melody gets its own chord so a passing note wont work. Good idea about adding the V7 though. I will try that because right now it sounds bland using V for all 3 notes.